# Convert String to Float in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following LINQ Query. Note that `DataValue` is a `string` value. I am trying to convert it to a float and then get the average.

```
var Avg = (from fd in DataContext.FormData
           select float.Parse(fd.DataValue)).Average();
```

I get the following error:

```
System.NotSupportedException: 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize 
the method 'Single Parse(System.String)' method, and this method 
cannot be translated into a store expression.'
```

Is there a good work around to this issue?

Comment: Either select the data into memory and then convert the values in an `IEnumerable` or write a custom SQL query to do the conversion and average.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not every C# function is a mapped function to SQL. Depending on the ORM you are using (I'm assuming EntityFframework), you can find a list of mapped functions in the ORM documentation.

Mapped function basically mean a C# function that the ORM maps/converts to an SQL function and add it to the end result SQL statement that gets executed by the ORM.

Read the documentation to be safe.

If you still want to use `Float.Parse`, then your only option is to materialize the query first then Parse, then Average. But that is not recommended.

Comment: `Convert.ToFloat` is not a valid function. It's `Convert.ToSingle` and this function isn't mapped to.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I wasn't sure what it was when I wrote the answer. But advised the person who asked to check the docs themselves.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use `Convert.ToSingle` instead of `float.Parse`:

```
var Avg = DataContext.FormData
    .Select(fd => DataContext.FormData(fd.DataValue))
    .Average();
```